# How to add meta tag to wordpress posts filter?

Tags: post-meta, description

For example, I have an url:

```
mysite.com/author/admin
```

It's not considered as single post or single page to add meta tag via SEO plugin. And to this page I want to add something like:

```
<meta name="description" content="All posts by author admin."/>
```

Is there are any way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What i get from your question the stuff related to author archive. If you're using yoast seo, for example, you can check setting inside Archive->Author Archive

Comment: Yeah, but from this menu I can't add meta tag to my url:
/author/admin
Maybe just hardcode it in header.php?

Comment: Can you share how the page at this url is created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a standerized way to add HTML meta tags in WordPress but you can use [`wp_head` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) as a generic way to add meta tags.

I think description meta tag should not be in the theme, as you suggest in your answer, because description meta tag is a property of the document, nothing to do with the look and feel of the document, that is, the theme.

This is a samlple code to do it:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'cyb_author_archive_meta_desc' );
function cyb_author_archive_meta_desc() {

   // Check is we are in author archive
   // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_author/
   if( is_author() ) {
       // get_queried_object() returns current author in author's arvhives
       // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/get_queried_object/
       $author = get_queried_object();

       // Generate meta description
       $description = sprintf( __( 'All posts by author %s', 'cyb-textdomain' ), $author->display_name );

       // Print description meta tag
       echo '<meta name="description" content="' . esc_attr( $description ) . '">';
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDT: Figured it out. Had to just hardcode it in header.php file located in my theme name folder.

```
<!-- Meta Tags -->

<?php if (is_archive() && !is_category()){
   echo '<meta property="og:description"  content="Your description"/>';
}
?>
```